Windows Remote Desktop working only one way
I tend to write too long posts, but I'll try to make it clear and as much info that I can provide.
Our company HAD ~20 PCs with local users and win10 and stormshieldVPN configured for ocasional home office. Its been wrorking ok, the user starts the VPN, then enters the IP for its PC on site and jumps right into it.
Last weeks we started roll out our newly bought win11 PCs. We went for domain login for each user since the ActiveDirectory groups and users were allready there for years.
Recently a first need to use RemoteDesktop araised and I can't figure out why it doesn't work.
I have a testing laptop with Win10pro, connected with my Android hotspot.

Connecting the laptop to Win11pro PC via IP results in an error like here [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/A2POEH38.jpg
Connecting connecting the laptop with any other Win10 PC works ok
Ping laptop<->Win11 works ok
Accessing shared Win11 files \192.168.0.125\files works ok
Connecting Win11 RDP to the laptop via IP works ok :o

What I did\test

remote desktop is ON on both devices
allowed users are added, but I dont even provide the login in RDP initial screen and I expect it to ask me for the credentials
laptop has default DNS, Win11 has 192.168.11 from the domain controller and for domain user-login
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" is set to 0 on both devices
on Win11 I added the remoteDesktop exe for allowed aplications in every type of connections public, private etc.
on Win11 I added a rule for port 3389 to allow in and out connections in every network type
Win11 has a "private" network type set, laptop aswell
RustDesk works if that info helps
file sharing and discovey is ON on both devices
I disabled firewall on Win11 completly but no result
"Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Connections > Allow users to connect remotely by using Remote Desktop Services" = Enabled
I noticed that laptop has subnet 255.255.255.252 and Win10 255.255.255.0
laptop -> Win11 "when doint Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 172.16.1.6 -Port 3389" got me "TcpTestSucceeded : True"
BUT "Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 192.168.0.1 -Port 3389" i got "pingSucceeded True; TcpTestSucceeded:False"
ChatGPT told me to add on Win11 "route add 172.16.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.16.1.5" but it didn't work

Maybe I'll try to wipe one of the PC without adding it to the domain and test if it works? It could be some default group policy?

Just to make sure we understand your problem: All works but with new Windows 11 pc it doesn't. All tests say it works, yet it does not connect. You make a hotspot with your android phone, then make VPN, then do RDP to the 192.168.0.1 (or whatever the ip for the win11 machine is) but it says computer is offline, correct?

Exactly. The funny part is that Win11 to the laptop with VPN (lets say its the user in his home) connects just fine. But the user via the laptop to the in-office Win11 PC (192.168.0.125) can't connect.
The same laptop can connect to older Win10 machines just fine

When you added the route you did use the appropriate subnet (in other words) the one you actually are using. ChatGPT would be unaware of what subnet you are using and often will hallucinates solutions.

I provided for ChatGPT the results of "route print" from both the PC I worked with. I wasn't capable of checking if its correct, but the hallucination should be limited with that info. Actually yesterday Chat got me an idea that I'll try this week and will get back with the result.
